# How To Make A Responsive Sidemenu In CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've finished coding my website for a 1024x768 resolution and now want to add @media queries to my code so that the sidebar disappears when the screen is at a width of 980px and then stays like that all the way down from there. I have tried adding the @media max-width 980 myself but it does not seem to be working at all. I've also tried in various places on the page but again, no luck. It's so frustrating! Code Below (Sorry if it's really long, I'm gonna leave it all in there to avoid any questions regarding code).

HTML:

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Lakeside Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masterstyle.css">
    <meta name="viewsize" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
            <h3 id="welcometext">Welcome To<br>Lakeside Books</h3>
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" ...Search Book Title" class="searchstyle"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: #333">
                    <a href="1Index.html" class="link">
                        <span style="color: #ed786a">Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="2Catgeories.html" class="link">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Bestsellers
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Find Us
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { /* ### */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: Arial, "Open Sans", sans-serif-light, sans-serif, "Segoe UI";
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 0 0 20%; /* ### */
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: #212528;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#nav {
    color: #DADADA;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover {
    background:#333;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.link {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
}
#nav li a:link{
    color: #DADADA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:visited{
    color: #DADADA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover{
    color: #DADADA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:active{
    color: #DADADA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#welcometext {
    text-align: center;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#searchbar {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: right;
}
#searchbar .searchstyle{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#searchbar input {
    max-width: 95%;
}

/*-------Media Styles-------*/

@media all and (max-width: 980px){
    #sidebar{
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't paste in enormous quantities of code, it makes it impossible for outsiders to debug. Try recreating the problem on plunkr or a similar service, then remove code in chunks until you've gotten rid of everything that isn't necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DSimon Shortened Code.

Comment: Did you mean display: none; instead of float: none'?

Comment: Matthew Rapati is right, either use display: none or visibility: hidden.

Comment: @MatthewRapati Thanks! But how can I turn that into a menu though? Like a button which will open and close the sidebar?

Comment: @SavageSpud there are lots of ways. Maybe you're looking for something like this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/ ?